# AngularJS Form validation - TypeError : Cannot set property 'integer' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation, angularjs-directive

I followed this [tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms) (Custom Validation) and I have this error when I load my html form using AngularJS custom validation. I'm using a directive called 'integer' in order to validate my number input in my form.

I don't know why I got this error because I have another personnal directive (excel cell validation) just before the integer one and I got no error.

Here is my number input :

```
<input type="number" ng-model="param.lineAct" class="form-control" min="0" integer />
```

And my directive :

```
var INTEGER_REGEXP = /^-?\d+$/;
adcAppDirectives.directive('integer', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link : function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$validators.integer = function (modelValue, viewValue){
                if (ctrl.$isEmpty(modelValue)) { return false};
                if (INTEGER_REGEXP.test(viewValue)) {return true};
                return false;
            };
        }
    };
});
```

This is how the error looks:

```
TypeError: Cannot set prpoerty 'integer' of undifined at link 127.0.0.1/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/js/…) input <type="number" ng-model="param.lineAct" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid" min="0" integer="">
```

EDIT : Here is the entire Directive javascript file :

```
var adcAppDirectives = angular.module('adcAppDirectives', []);

var INTEGER_REGEXP = /^\-?\d+$/;
var EXCELCEL_REGEXP = /^[A-Z]+[0-9]+/;
var EXCELCELS_REGEXP = /^[A-Z]+[0-9]+:[A-Z]+[0-9]+/;
var EXCELCOL_REGEXP = /^[A-Z]+/;

adcAppDirectives.directive('integer', function()
{
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$validators.integer = function (modelValue, viewValue) {
                if (ctrl.$isEmpty(modelValue)){
                    return false;
                }
                if (INTEGER_REGEXP.test(viewValue)) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
    };
});

adcAppDirectives.directive('excel-cel', function()
{
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$validators.excel_cel = function (modelValue, viewValue) {
                if (ctrl.$isEmpty(modelValue)){
                    return false;
                }
                if (EXCELCEL_REGEXP.test(viewValue)) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            };
        }
    };
});

adcAppDirectives.directive('excel-cels', function()
{
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$validators.excel_cels = function (modelValue, viewValue) {
                if (ctrl.$isEmpty(modelValue)){
                    return false;
                }
                if (EXCELCELS_REGEXP.test(viewValue)) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            };
        }
    };
});

adcAppDirectives.directive('excel-col', function()
{
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$validators.excel_col = function (modelValue, viewValue) {
                if (ctrl.$isEmpty(modelValue)){
                    return false;
                }
                if (EXCELCOL_REGEXP.test(viewValue)) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            };
        }
    };
});
```

And the html :

```
<form name="form" novalidate class="simple-form">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    Nom: <input type="text" ng-model="param.Name" class="form-control" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    Plage de paramètres: <input type="text" ng-model="param.paramTitle" class="form-control" excel-cels />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    Ligne des traitements: <input type="number" ng-model="param.lineAct" class="form-control" min="0" integer />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    Colonne de la DIR: <input type="text" ng-model="param.dirCol" class="form-control" excel-col />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success col-lg-offset-6 col-lg-2">Valider</button>
                            </div>
                            </form>
```

Comment: Could you please add the error as well? I mean copy paste as is.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot set prpoerty 'integer' of undifined at link http://127.0.0.1/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/js/71229cb_Directives_9.js:13:32) input <type="number" ng-model="param.lineAct" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid" min="0" integer="">

Comment: Have you injected the integer directive into the controller?

Comment: The error should be in the question, not in a comment and it looks like you spelt it wrong in the comment

Comment: @simpe: Do you mean this line : var adcAppDirectives = angular.module('adcAppDirectives', []);

Comment: @WayneEllery: The error is in my post title like I said. Do you mean that I should write my error in my question not in my title?

Comment: It shouldn't just be in the title, you should also post it in the question content.

Comment: Ok I see I'll do it the next time

Comment: @simpe: And in the developer guide, the example doesn't inject the directive into the controller. I'm new to AngularJS so I don't everything about it.

Comment: Can you paste the whole html code you are using? or better put in a plunker?

Comment: I wanted to check the angular version you were using, see blint answer which explains why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade to the latest version of AngularJS: `formController.$validators` is new in Angular 1.3

If you can't, refer to the documentation of yours. Here's the form guide for 1.2: https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/docs/guide/forms

Comment: I'm using 1.2.28 you are right. I'm changing the code.

Comment: I'm glad you're unstuck, have fun with angular ;-)